# Appropriate to use closure in python classes when parameters are constant?

Tags: python

This is a question about coding convention and whether or not something is "pythonic" or good practice.

Say I have a python class like this:

```
class ClassName:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg1 = arg2
        self.arg1 = arg3
        self.arg1 = arg4
        self.arg1 = arg5

        self.some_var = 0


    def some_function1(self):
        make use of self.arg1, self.arg2
        modify self.some_var

    def some_function2(self):
        make use of self.arg3, self.arg4, self.arg5
        modify self.some_var
```

where all of the `arg`s are to be treated as constants for use in computations and methods throughout the class.

Rather than doing this, I have sometimes used the following pattern:

```
class ClassName:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5):
        self.some_var = 0

        self.some_function1 = self.some_function1(arg1, arg2)
        self.some_function2 = self.some_function2(arg3, arg4, arg5)

    def some_function1(self, arg1, arg2):
        def inner():
            make use of arg1, arg2
            modify self.some_var
        return inner

    def some_function2(self, arg3, arg4, arg5):
        def inner():
            make use of arg3, arg4, arg5
            modify self.some_var
        return inner
```

Because the variables we pass to the `__init__` method are just used as constants in certain computations, it makes sense to, rather than making them member variables, bind them to a function closure (thus giving them more appropriate scope). However, I think that while it makes sense to do this, it is unusual and may not be obvious what the point is to some people.

Is this bad form, or does it make sense?

Comment: I personally find the first one easier to read, if you are going to be sharing your code to a larger group then go with the first one.

Comment: It makes more sense to get rid of the class and just pass the arguments to the functions as-is IMO.

Comment: @rdas Except when the functions have side effects. The point of the class is to avoid beginning every function with a long string of global variables. I should have been more clear about this point.

Comment: @AlexVandeKleut From your question I assumed those were pure functions. If not, I would prefer option 1. Much easier to read.

Comment: I think the second way is super-confusing, in particular how you re-define the two `some_functions` in `__init__` from retuning a function to _being_ that function...

Comment: @rdas I have edited it to explicitly include side effects.

Comment: @tobias_k I could rename them `some_function1_closure` for example, but that isn't really the crux of the question. Good point though.

Comment: I would consider this confusing and anti-idiomatic. This really depends on what you want for you code, is it going to be maintained by other python programmers as well?

Answer (score 1):

The next maintainer to come along would absolutely hate you. Where did this method come from? Why does it have a different signature based on whether I'm looking at a class or an instance? How do I subclass this thing?

Don't do that. Remember, "explicit is better than implicit". If you're using `self.foo` in a method, actually refer to it as `self.foo` so that the next person can tell at a glance where it's defined. And honestly, it's very likely that the next person will be you, six months from now, at 2 AM when something has broken and you're trying to troubleshoot it. The mind you save may be your own.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is going to be pretty subjective and I can't claim much authority here, so take with a pinch of salt.

I don't think using closures is inherently unPythonic, but I think the pattern of masking a method on the class with a bound closure on the instance is getting well into unPythonic territory. It's making me wonder whether one class containing definitions for `some_function1` and `some_function2` is really the most natural abstraction here. It doesn't even look like they use `self` even though they receive it as a parameter? Perhaps they are more logically independent entities (classes/functions), instances of which might be owned by an instance of the class?

Comment: I have edited the question to include the fact that the functions have side effects / modify/rely on member variables of the class.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't necessarily do it like you did and find it rather strange to read.

I have a few potential solutions to your problem - one being massively ugly but I included it anyway.

```
from functools import partial

class A():
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        self.B = self.B(self, arg1, arg2)
        self.arg3 = arg3

    class SomeFunction():
        def __init__(self, parent, arg1, arg2):
            self.parent = parent
            self.arg1 = arg1
            self.arg2 = arg2

        def __call__(self):
            self.parent.arg3 = 5
            return self.arg1 + self.arg2

class B():
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        self.some_function = partial(self.some_function, arg1=arg1, arg2=arg2)
        self.arg3 = arg3

    def some_function(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.arg3 *= 5
        return arg1 + arg2
```

In class `A` you define the function as a callable class and then redefine it in `__init__` to be an instance on your `A` instance. This is the ugly one.

In class `B` I utilize `functools.partial` to replace the method with another method but fixing the arguments to `arg1` and `arg2`. This technically probably works something like the approach in `A` but is way more readable and doesn't require any change of the function itself which is a plus imo.

Another way to do it would be like this:

```
class C():
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        self.some_function = lambda: self._some_function(arg1, arg2)
        self.arg3 = arg3

    def _some_function(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.arg3 *= 5
        return arg1 + arg2
```

So actually defining the function via a lambda that delegates the actual operation to `_some_function` which again leaves the function implementation untouched. Since you used "closure" as a term you may be familiar with the concept of a stealing closure from rust(or the language rust got it from...), which this essentially is.
I also tried around a bit with using a function/class decorator but I don't think they can be utilized here since they can't access the arguments on call.

Imo using `B` or `C` is fine, with preference of `C`.